# After recent update, pug get is not working. any ideas?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Today (22.08.2020) after being prompted on Android Studio, i updated flutter. After that, whenever i do a pub get, i get the following error:

"Because every version of flutter from sdk depends on vector_math 2.1.0-nullsafety.2 which doesn't match any versions, flutter from sdk is forbidden.
So, because flutter_app3 depends on flutter any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_app3 depends on flutter any from sdk, version solving failed.)"

see below flutter doctor -v result:

```
C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\flutter_app3>flutter doctor -v
```

[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.21.0-9.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1667], locale cs-CZ)
• Flutter version 1.21.0-9.1.pre at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision be9bc8cb39 (4 days ago), 2020-08-18 09:46:08 -0700
• Engine revision 267070c17a
• Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-7.2.beta)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
• Dart plugin version 193.7361
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.47.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• HD1903 (mobile) • aa3eee24 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

• No issues found!

pubspec.yaml:

```html
name: flutter_app3
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your dependencies in pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: no depedences.. new flutter project template.do you still need to see it?

Comment: You used the channel beta flutter. I think you need to use the stable channel :)

Comment: if you add this as an answer, i will put is as the answer to the question. I do not know why it switched channels by itself. But going back to stable fixed the issue.

Comment: Sure, I put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the channel beta flutter.
I think you need to use the stable channel.

Comment: Thank you. this is the answer. When changed back to the stable channel after the update. everything was back to normal